# Estimate (calculate) dimensions of HTML elements (for book paging)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all I'll describe the purpose.

I've got a problem of  calculating Book Paging when the size of the window (viewport) is 
changed. I would like to calculate all the pages in the book depending on current viewport size (and maybe other parameters as font size). Quite heavy task for the browser if I will render the elements it in invisible layer to get is size and calculate.

Is there a way somehow to estimate (actually calculate) the dimensions of HTML element more effectively (maybe without rendering it with jquery).

Answer (score 1):

if you render while it has visibility:hidden, it will still have dimension.

For width use document.getElementById('someid').offsetWidth

For height use document.getElementById('someid').offsetHeight

For the viewport use window.availWidth and window.availHeight

Comment: The problem is that rendering big amount of html data take too much time.

Comment: If you have a large amount of data; it is going to take a lot of time no matter what you do.  The time it takes to do the calculations and rendering for a page is a few ms.  The size for a page is not going to change unless the user re-sizes, and the re-calc is still just going to be a few ms.  You cannot expect a browser to work like a Kindle;  they ae different technologies.  Browsers are optimized to present small amounts of data quickly and flexibly, and you are fighting against that optimization.  Use the browser speed by caching a few pages, bring more in with AJAX in background.

Comment: By Kindle I mean Kindle Web App (http://read.amazon.com). It seems that there is needed some sophisticated algorithm for approximate estimation of the size of the content (considering current the rules of styling, formatting and container size) without need of rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of any given element are dependent on a whole bunch of different factors, including the CSS, contents and browser handling of that element. To calculate the actual height programmatically, you would have to interpret and calculate all these different variables. You might be able to get a rough estimate by looking at the number of words or lines being rendered within an element, but it wouldn't be exact.

Rendering the element first is the only way to know the true dimensions the browser has rendered it as. If you can use some clever logic to only process one page at a time as the user views it, you might be able to solve your performance issue.

Comment: Well, its not difficult to process one page at a time (for example as kindle (all their readers software including web reader) does. But Google books, seems to do the calcualtions, but It does not calculate the all he pages (the number of the pages is static in all books, and that number actually means nothing for digital book) - its to quite easy to implement. The I know only who does such full calculations (through out a whole book) is Apple iBooks app, but they have the solid Text Core framework and for that purpose. And for the web It seems that its quite heavy topic for browsers=(